# Let callables/threads work on copy of an object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, dijkstra, callable

I have a working code, in which I calculate the shortest path from every point (Dijkstra's algorithm) to every point in a graph.

But as soon as I want to use more than 1 thread with my ExecuterService, they all will work on the same graph for calculating the results, which of course makes the result unusable.

How can I make it so that one thread gets an own copy of the graph, so the callables run on that thread won't disturb the others? Is that even possible?

Comment: just provide a proper copy method for your graph and let other threads work on the copied graph.

Comment: How do I tell different callables on which graph they should run?
It depends on which thread their running on.

Comment: Can you provide some brief code? I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is this a question about the Java concurrency API or about the graph structure you made yourself?

Answer (score 0):

As [Keqiang Li commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531603/let-callables-threads-work-on-copy-of-an-object-in-java#comment-60667064), you need to define a mechanism for copying the single graph data structure you already have. However, since you obviously need to first build the structure itself before creating multiple copies of it, one commonly-used trick is to use a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) in order to create immutable objects on which you will actually do the search. Note that this needn't be implemented in an actual separate e.g. `GraphBuilder` class but rather you can simply implement a mechanism for creating immutable copies of a single mutable graph structure which you initially build incrementally while reading in your data:

```
public class MutableDirectedGraph implements DirectedGraph {

    public MutableDirectedGraph() {
        ...
    }

    public Edge addEdge(final Node start, final Node end, final String label, final double weight) {
        ...
    }

    public Node addNode() {
        ...
    }

     ...
}

public class ImmutableDirectedGraph implements DirectedGraph {

    public ImmutableDirectedGraph(final DirectedGraph copyee) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

One nice thing about this approach is that you can implement `MutableDirectedGraph` to be easy to modify/build in an incremental fashion and then implement `ImmutableDirectedGraph` with optimizations for searching (e.g. storing `Edge` objects by their respective IDs in an array for memory-efficient storage while using `Map`-based storage in the mutable version). In this way, making two separate classes for two specific tasks may be quicker for the programmer as well as for the computer to deal with.

Comment: @Reyny: If this answer helped you out, I'd be very grateful if you could [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) as I'm currently trawling for a few extra reputation points. Plus, it also give you a few extra points, too. Thanks a lot for the help.